# Running a void function for specific time

Tags: c, linux, time, void

i am using linux and have writen a .c file . I want to use some functions of type void to perform the movement of a motor . I am aiming at moving it forward for 2 seconds , then turn right for another 2 etc. How can i achieve it ?  The functions MOVE_FORW , MOVE_RIGHT etc are void.

The function has return type void. My problem is how i am going to get the system to perform the task i want for a real time of 2 seconds . What kind of delay should i use ?

Here is the code : 
I want to control two wheels via a motor. The names are symbolic :

```
/*
 DEFINITIONS

 FLEN FILE LEFT ENABLE   GPIO177
 FREN FILE RIGHT ENABLE  GPIO168
 FLC FILE LEFT C  GPIO166
 FRC FILE RIGHT C GPIO169
 FLD FILE LEFT D GPIO167
 FRD FILE RIGHT D  GPIO170

 LEH LEFT ENABLE HIGH
 LEL LEFT ENABLE LOW
 LCH LEFT C HIGH
 LCL LEFT C LOW
 LDH LEFT D HIGH
 LDL LEFT D LOW

 REH RIGHT ENABLE HIGH
 REL RIGHT ENABLE LOW
 RCH RIGHT C HIGH
 RCL RIGHT C LOW
 RDH RIGHT D HIGH
 RDL RIGHT D LOW
*/

FILE *FLEN,*FREN,*FLC,*FRC,*FLD,*FRD;

FILE *DIR_FLEN,*DIR_FREN,*DIR_FLC,*DIR_FRC,*DIR_FLD,*DIR_FRD;

//LEFT WHEEL
#define LEH() fprintf(FLEN,"1")
#define LEL() fprintf(FLEN,"0")
#define LCH() fprintf(FLC,"1")
#define LCL() fprintf(FLC,"0")
#define LDH() fprintf(FLD,"1")
#define LDL() fprintf(FLD,"0")

//RIGHT WHEEL
#define REH() fprintf(FREN,"1")
#define REL() fprintf(FREN,"0")
#define RCH() fprintf(FRC,"1")
#define RCL() fprintf(FRC,"0")
#define RDH() fprintf(FRD,"1")
#define RDL() fprintf(FRD,"0")


void MOVE_FORW(){
LEH();
LCH();
LDL();
REH();
RCH();
RDL();
}



void MOVE_BCKW(){
LEH();
LCL();
LDH();
REH();
RCL();
RDH();
}

void MOVE_RIGHT(){
LEH();
LCH();
LDL();
REH();
RCL();
RDH();
}


void MOVE_LEFT(){
LEH();
LCL();
LDH();
REH();
RCH();
RDL();
}



int main(void){

//HANDLING FILES - opening files fow writing ( overwriting )

//EXPORTING AS OUTPUT - DEFINING DIRECTION (out)

system("echo 177 > /sys/class/gpio/export");
printf("FINE\n");

DIR_FLEN=fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio177/direction","w+"); //GPIO 177
fprintf(DIR_FLEN,"out");
FLEN=fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio177/value","w+"); //GPIO 177



system("echo 168 > /sys/class/gpio/export");
DIR_FREN=fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio168/direction","w+"); //GPIO 168
fprintf(DIR_FREN,"out");
FREN=fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio168/value","w+"); //GPIO 168


system("echo 166 > /sys/class/gpio/export");
DIR_FLC=fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio166/direction","w+");
fprintf(DIR_FLC,"out");
FLC=fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio166/value","w+");


system("echo 169 > /sys/class/gpio/export");
DIR_FRC=fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio169/direction","w+");
fprintf(DIR_FRC,"out");
FRC=fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio169/value","w+");


system("echo 167 > /sys/class/gpio/export");
DIR_FLD=fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio167/direction","w+");
fprintf(DIR_FLD,"out");
FLD=fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio167/value","w+");


system("echo 170> /sys/class/gpio/export");
DIR_FRD=fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio170/direction","w+");
fprintf(DIR_FRD,"out");
FRD=fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio170/value","w+");


MOVE_FORW();
```

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question._

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. By "functions of type void" do you mean the functions have return type `void` or take `void` parameters? In either case, why is the `void` an issue? Just call it. Please clarify your question. Best if you show some concrete code to make it clearer.

Comment: There is a massive void in your question - the space where the code should be:(

Comment: Can't you just get the start time and then keep calling the move function in a loop until the current time is 2 seconds pass the start time?

Comment: Can't you just tell me how to do this ? That is what i am asking for .

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to get the current time? Have a look at [`gettimeofday`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) or [`clock_gettime`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it simply :

```
void MOVE_FORW(){
LEH();
LCH();
LDL();
REH();
RCH();
RDL();
system("sleep 3");
}



void MOVE_BCKW(){
LEH();
LCL();
LDH();
REH();
RCL();
RDH();
system("sleep 3");
}

void MOVE_RIGHT(){
LEH();
LCH();
LDL();
REH();
RCL();
RDH();
system("sleep 3");
}


void MOVE_LEFT(){
LEH();
LCL();
LDH();
REH();
RCH();
RDL();
system("sleep 3");
}
```

Thanks for your try and thoughts any way !